# Deleting an item by $index or indexOf() results in deleting all items in ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

I have an Ionic List with items including an attribute from the directive ion-delete-button (see [docs](http://ionicframework.com/docs/api/directive/ionDeleteButton/)).

I fill the list using ng-repeat in the following matter:

**HTML**

```
<ion-list>

<ion-item class="item item-thumbnail-left item-text-wrap" 
                ng-repeat="albumname in Albums track by $index" 
                href="#/tab/dash/{{Albums[$index]}}">

                <img ng-src="{{thumbnailImage(albumname, 'album')}}" class="thumbnail-album">

                <h2 style="padding-top: 20px">{{albumname}}</h2>

                <!--WORKS FINE, CHANGES NAME OF $index -->
                <ion-option-button class="button-energized"   ng-click="changeAlbumName($index)">Change Name</ion-option-button> 

                <!-- DOES NOT WORK AS EXPECTED, ON PHONE DELETES ALL ALBUMS -->
                <ion-delete-button class="ion-minus-circled"  ng-click="deleteAlbum($index)"></ion-delete-button> 

      </ion-item>

</ion-list>
```

**Controller**

```
// Initialized and Refreshed on Updates
$scope.Albums = DashFactory.getAlbums();

$scope.deleteAlbum = function(index) {
    console.log(index) // SHOWS CORRECT INDEX
    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
      title: 'Delete Album: ' + $scope.Albums[index],
      template: 'Are you sure you want to delete this album?'
    });
    confirmPopup.then(function(res) {
      if(res) {
        console.log('You are sure');
        DashFactory.deleteAlbum(index); // SERVICE FOR DELETING THE ALBUM
        $ionicListDelegate.showDelete(false);
      } else {
        console.log('You are not sure');
      }
    });
  }
```

**Service (DashFactory)**

```
var Albums = ['foobut', 'barplug', 'fooin', 'barass']

var deleteAlbum = function(index) {
        Albums.splice(index);
        this.saveAlbums();
};
var getAlbums = function() {
        return Albums;
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Array.splice need more than one parameter, it will now remove everything starting from the index you gave. Try Album.splice(index,1);

See : http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Answer (score 0):

Solved it. Basically you have to write:

```
Array.splice(index, amount)
```

where amount is 1, the number of items you are removing. Otherwise it removes it all.